# Open a new activity from a class string. Class null

Tags: android

In an fragment I want to open a new activity, but class is extracted by string. In toast receive myclass.class, but not open a new class, and if change "c" from a new class, the code is work fine.

Code:

```
if (item instanceof Movie) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Item: " + item.toString());
    String page = item.toString();
    String pageFinal = page + ".class";
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Class<?> c = null;
    if(pageFinal != null) {
        try {
            c = Class.forName(pageFinal);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), c);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);

}
```

Log:

```
03-07 08:42:19.872 18138-18138/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming W/System.err:            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
03-07 08:42:19.872 18138-18138/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-07 08:42:19.872 18138-18138/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming, PID: 18138
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Class.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:129)
                                                                                 at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4449)
                                                                                 at ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.MainFragment$ItemViewClickedListener.onItemClicked(MainFragment.java:71)
                                                                                 at android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ListRowPresenter$ListRowPresenterItemBridgeAdapter$1.onClick(ListRowPresenter.java:243)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-07 08:42:22.304 18138-18138/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18138 SIG: 9
```

### Edit

Movie.java

```
public class Movie { 

   private static final String TAG = Movie.class.getSimpleName();

    static final long serialVersionUID = 727566175075960653L;
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String studio;
    private String description;
    private String cardImageUrl;

    public String getCardImageUrl() {
        return cardImageUrl;
    }

    public void setCardImageUrl(String cardImageUrl) {
        this.cardImageUrl = cardImageUrl;
    }
    public Movie() {
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getStudio() {
        return studio;
    }

    public void setStudio(String studio) {
        this.studio = studio;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        /*
        return "Movie{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                '}';
                */
        return title;
    }
    public URI getCardImageURI() {
        try {
            return new URI(getCardImageUrl());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create a Movie instance? Post the content of a movie object.

Comment: Add the code that creates a new Movie instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `Class.forName(className)` method, `className` has to be constructed from your package name and your `Class` name without the `.class` extension.

For `ro.movieapp.activities.MovieActivity.class` your call should be something like this: `Class.forName("ro.movieapp.activities.MovieActivity")`.

That being said, it is a really bad idea to do it because it's an easy source of bugs (your question is a good example). You should keep a reference to your activity's `Class` inside your `Movie` object.

My suggestion is to do something like this:

```
class Movie {

    private Class<?> activityClass;

    public <C extends AppCompatActivity> void setActivityClass(Class<C> activityClass) {
        this.activityClass = activityClass;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <C extends AppCompatActivity> Class<C> getActivityClass() {
        return (Class<C>) activityClass;
    }
}

...

final Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.setActivityClass(MovieActivity.class);

...

final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), movie.getActivityClass());
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Class.forName method takes class name parameter which has to be full path of class.

Eg. if your activity is  in package com.example.activity.SampleActivity

then method should be called like

```
Class<?> c=Class.forName("com.example.activity.SampleActivity");
```

make sure you are getting correct class name from page.toString().

Comment: i added this and now is work "com.example.activity."

Comment: @diaconuliviu  It's a really bad idea! This thing is such an easy source of bugs. The first proof would be you asking this question on stackoverflow. Push yourself into becoming a better software developer, don't hack your way through.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: If you move your `SampleActivity` from package `com.example.activity` to another package, let's say `ro.moviesapp.activity`, you also have to change your `Class.forName("com.example.activity" + className)` method call, and there is a very big chance you WILL forget to do it. => new bug.

Comment: String page = item.toString();
                String pageFinal = "ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming." + page;

Comment: Your code is more complex, and thank you much. I will now try on to make sure I'm right. Thank you